# Mark Jenkins build as success, in case of timeout on input? (declarative pipeline)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm creating a declarative Jenkins pipeline, that looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'mylabel'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Install dependencies') {
            milestone()
            steps {
                sh "yarn install"
            }
        }
        stage('Lint files') {
            steps {
                sh "eslint src"
            }
        }
        stage('Create bundle') {
            steps {
                sh "yarn run build:server"
                sh "yarn run build:client"
            }
        }
        stage('Publish') {
            steps {
                timeout(time: 15, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                    input(message: 'Deploy this build to QA?')
                }
                // deployment steps
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It works great, however, if the timeout step fails (because we don't want to deploy this build, or nobody is there to push the button, and so on), the build is marked with status "aborted". Unfortunately this means that for example Github marks our pull requests as "checks failing".

Is there a way to declare the build with the status that it had before the timeout() step? Eg. if the build was a success up until the timeout step, it should be marked as success, even if the timeout happens.

Answer (score 18):

Since all you want is to let the build abort without marking it as failed, you can just add a simple `try/catch` to your code.

```
        stage('Publish') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def proceed = true
                    try {
                        timeout(time: 15, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                            input(message: 'Deploy this build to QA?')
                        }
                    } catch (err) {
                        proceed = false
                    }
                    if(proceed) {
                        // deployment steps
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If a user aborts the build or it times out, the error is suppressed, the build is still a success, and the deployment steps won't execute.

Answer (score 8):

We have a situation where we don't want to start a build if there are no user commits. Because of a bug in the scm trigger prevention on message or user.
What we then do is fail the build with a NOT_BUILT result.

Maybe this will also work for your situation

Try the following in your script

```
try {
    stage ('wait') {
        timeout(time: 15, unit: 'SECONDS') {
            input(message: 'Deploy this build to QA?')
        } 
    }
} catch (err) {
    def user = err.getCauses()[0].getUser()
    if('SYSTEM' == user.toString()) { //timeout
        currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like this syntax can be used for declarative pipelines, I get `WorkflowScript: 38: Expected a stage @ line 38, column 9.`. Line 38 is the try block.

Comment: I think in the declarative pipeline the try should be inside the stage block.
This snippet was tested as an inline pipeline script in a pipeline job

Comment: I have tried moving it around, inside stage, inside steps, none of them seems to work

Comment: In declarative pipelines the post section is used instead of try/catch: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the job to be marked as "aborted" or "failed":

For a Declarative pipeline (not a scripted) you would do something like this

```
    stage('Foo') {
          steps {
                script {
                    env.PROCEED_TO_DEPLOY = 1
                    try {
                        timeout(time: 2, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                            // ...
                        }
                    } catch (err) {
                        env.PROCEED_TO_DEPLOY = 0
                    }
                }
          }
      }
      stage('Bar') {
        when {
            expression {
                env.PROCEED_TO_DEPLOY == 1
            }
        }
        //rest of your pipeline
```

stage "Bar" would be skipped but as for the rest of the stages the job will be marked as passed (assuming nothing wrong happened before)

Answer (score -1):

You could probably adjust `currentBuild.result` in `post` section of declarative pipeline.

E.g.

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    ...
  }
  post {
    aborted {
      script {
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: no... this is not working. Looks like in declarative pipeline currentBuild.result doesn't change anythng.

Comment: In fact, even an echo in a post-aborted-section didn't get executed. Could be linked to this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43339

Comment: Actually, this may be because currentBuild.result has been set to something worse than SUCCESS already and cannot be re-raised, even (somewhat) in the same stage.