# How to mark build success when one of the stages is aborted?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline with stages where one of the stages, intermittently takes longer than expected and hence using `timeout` to abort it. But if the stage is aborted, build also marked as aborted. Following is the code for the pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('First') {
            options {
                timeout(time: 10, unit: 'SECONDS')
            }
            steps {
                script {

                    catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS') {
                        echo "Executing stage I"
                        sleep 12
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        stage('Second') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Executing stage II"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even though the stage is marked as `Aborted`, I want to mark build as `Success`. Can you please help how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest one improvement to Michael's answer (which is correct btw). You can use `catchError` to mark stage `ABORTED` (or `UNSTABLE`) and mark the build `SUCCESS`, but you need to wrap the code that may timeout with `try-catch` block to control the error. Consider the following example:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('First') {
            options {
                timeout(time: 3, unit: 'SECONDS')
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'ABORTED') {
                        try {
                            echo "Executing stage I"
                            sleep 4
                        } catch(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException e) {
                            error "Stage interrupted with ${e.toString()}"
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        stage('Second') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Executing stage II"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you run this pipeline, the stage that timed out is marked as `ABORTED`, but the pipeline continues and if there is no failure in the remaining stages, it is marked as `SUCCESS`.

[image]

And here is what the `UNSTABLE` stage status looks like.

[image]

Michael's solution works as well, but it produces a slightly different result - the stage that times out is marked as `SUCCESS`, and this might be less intuitive. You need to click on the stage to check if it timed out or not.

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('First') {
            options {
                timeout(time: 3, unit: 'SECONDS')
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        echo "Executing stage I"
                        sleep 4
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Second') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Executing stage II"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is what I was looking for! I wanted to  mark aborted not Success but something different and still mark build as Success. Stage's current unstable status is helping to identify something wrong there. Thanks a lot! Michael's solution was also working but it was marking aborted stage as 'green'.

Comment: @TDHM, you can also set stage status to `ABORTED` if you prefer to mark this stage gray instead of `UNSTABLE`. It will work as well.

Comment: Yes. I updated the answer to include the `ABORTED` stage status.

Answer (score 2):

Your `catchError()` won't work in your case. The documantation ([Source](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/)) tells the following:

> buildResult (optional)
>
> If an error is caught, the overall build result
>   will be set to this value. **Note that the build result can only get
>   worse, so you cannot change the result to SUCCESS if the current
>   result is UNSTABLE or worse.** Use SUCCESS or null to keep the build
>   result from being set when an error is caught.

The build status is set with `currentBuild.currentResult` which can have three values: `SUCCESS`, `UNSTABLE`, or `FAILURE`.

If you want to mark the build as `SUCCESS` on abortion the post-option ([Source](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post)) `aborted` can be used:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        aborted { 
            // Executed only if stage is aborted
            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this way I can mark build as `SUCCESS` even if stage fails. I was looking for something mark build as `SUCCESS` even if stage is aborted.

Comment: The answer should fit better to your question now.

Comment: I had tried the same before but did not work. Please refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494238/mark-jenkins-build-as-success-in-case-of-timeout-on-input-declarative-pipelin/49277913#49277913

Comment: Thanks Michael for your efforts and all the details you've put in here! Your earlier answer which you edited was also helpful but Szymon's answer make it more clear about stage failure and still mark build as success.

Comment: No worries! I am glad you found your solution :)